# Viewpoint parameter closing tags issue

Tags: javascript, html

I am setting up javascript to display advertising network banner code for 728x90 on screens larger than 767. If width of screen is less, it would display the 300x250 banner code only. When I add the below code it shows nothing on web and mobile, just an empty space. I am working inside wordpress if that helps.

```
    <div class="container">ՙ



<script>
window.onresize = function(){

var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
var script = document.createElement('script');

if ( $(window).width() <= 767) {

e9 = new Object();
e9.size = "320x50";
script.src = "http://tags.expo9.exponential.com/tags/ProwrestlingcomMobile/320x50/tags.js";
head.appendChild(script);

}else {

e9 = new Object();
e9.size = "728x90";
script.src = "http://tags.expo9.exponential.com/tags/ProWrestlingcom/ROS/tags.js";
head.appendChild(script);

}
}
</script>
</div>
```

Original 728x90 ad code:

```
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
               e9 = new Object();
    e9.size = "728x90,970x250";
//--></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://tags.expo9.exponential.com/tags/ProWrestlingcom/ROS/tags.js"></script>
```

Original 300x250 ad code:

```
<script type="text/javascript"><!--

               e9 = new Object();

    e9.size = "320x50";

//--></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://tags.expo9.exponential.com/tags/ProwrestlingcomMobile/320x50/tags.js"></script>
```

Comment: There are lot of errors due to the incorrect use of script tag (opened and not closed)

Comment: @Pierfrancesco I fixed it with new code

Comment: Silly question: is jQuery included on the page?  Are there any errors in the developer console?  Also, what's the point of the `e9` object?

Comment: Unrelated to your answer, but I would also remove the `head` & `script` vars from inside the event listener. You don't want to be redefining those on window resize.

Comment: Are you sure that tags.js needs to be appended in the head? Or it has to be inserted in the  `<div class="container">` ?
Moreover I've noticed a strange character after <div class="container">: this one ---> ՙ <----

Comment: @ScottKaye the e9 is part of the tag code received from network. I updated the post to include original tags. As I am trying to show the 728x90 for screens larger than 768 width, and anything smaller would show 300x250.

Answer (score 2):

Two problems with this code:

1) window.onresize will get called several times on resizing the window, resulting in the script tag being added multiple times

2) window.onresize will only get called on resize, not on load. window.onload will get called once, adding the script. So perhaps just change window.onresize => window.onload

Answer (score 0):

You can use `<iframe`> elements and `css` media queries to toggle two `<iframe>` elements with `src` set to `html` containing `<script>` for `728x50` , `300x250` respectively

style.css

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  iframe[src="728.html"] {
    display: none;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 767px) {
  iframe[src="300.html"] {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
  <iframe src="728.html" width="728px" height="90px" style="border:none;" scrolling="no"></iframe>
  <iframe src="300.html" width="300px" height="250px" style="border:none;" scrolling="no"></iframe>
  </body>
</html>
```

300.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body style="background:green;width:320px;height:250px;">
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
    e9 = new Object();
    e9.size = "320x50";
//--></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://tags.expo9.exponential.com/tags/ProwrestlingcomMobile/320x50/tags.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

728.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body style="background:blue;width:728px;height:50px;">
  <script type="text/javascript"><!--
    e9 = new Object();
    e9.size = "728x90,970x250";
//--></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://tags.expo9.exponential.com/tags/ProWrestlingcom/ROS/tags.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

plnkr http://plnkr.co/edit/L7yWvl9YGLpBtIKWT87x?p=preview